# WCF : Registering a service AND its config file

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, excel

I am building an RTD Server for Excel, that is embedding a WCF Service to be exposed to receive data.
I need to register the Assembly DLL using RegAsm (for Excel to see it and use it).
I was wondering if the web.config containing service configuration was "lost" during this operation or was it still referenced "somewhere somehow" by the deployed/registered Service DLL.

I have a doubt because I added system.diagnostics to the config file and the output listener file is not created.

**Edit : Solution**
creating an Excel.exe.config an putting the config in it solved the issue.
See [A Beginner’s Guide to calling a .NET Library from Excel](http://richnewman.wordpress.com/2007/04/15/a-beginner%E2%80%99s-guide-to-calling-a-net-library-from-excel/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not 'lost' per se - you still have the file ;)

You need to add the configuration information to Excel.exe.config, that's where the runtime will look for the configuration data.

Comment: Jeez. Are you sure ? And what if I have different WCF services with different settings ? including them in Excel.exe.config would be a mess

Comment: Seems like you're right : http://blog.ilab8.com/2011/01/28/excel-dna/ (click on illustration to enlarge)

Comment: @Mika: You might be able to stuff them in Machine.config (more likely), or in User.settings (less likely).  It also seems you can import other files if you specify it correctly?  See this article: http://blog.rlucas.net/bugfix/web-config-and-app-config-file-gotchas/ (although now I've just reread that blob to try it out, it seems that file import stuff might only apply to the `appSettings` section)